# Fullscreen Application Position in Expose in OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, fullscreen, desktop, spaces, apple-expose

What I'm trying to figure out is how to move assign a place for an application in full screen mode in relationship to desktops. Basically, I would like some apps to be in front of the desktops when they are started, for instance, a fullscreened iTerm session with a certain title. So, to graphically, it would look like this:
...

[image: iTerm, Desktop 1, Desktop 2]

Or in text:

```
[iTerm]  [Desktop 1]  [Desktop 2] etc.
```

Instead of:

[image: Desktop 1, Desktop 2, iTerm]

```
[Desktop 1]  [Desktop 2]  [iTerm]
```

(I assume this would be automated via Apple Script somehow, if I figure it out before someone replies, I'll update this post).

Comment: If you want to post links to your images, I'll edit your post to add them. This question *is* off-topic for Stack Overflow, though (it might be better suited for [Super User SE](http://superuser.com/)) so I'll flag it for migration.

Comment: @computerfreaker Sounds good, here are the images:

    1. http://i.imgur.com/CaRlBm1.png  

    2. http://i.imgur.com/UG6q4lQ.png